# React Native Redux subscribing to store changes

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm building a shopping cart using React native and Redux. There are some actions such as addToCart and removeFromCart which changes the products array within store. I have two question:

1) How can we update store fields like totalPrice of cart? Should I subscribe to the store changes and update the items accordingly? Should one ever subsribe to the store within React Native context and call utility functions

2) My Add to Cart reducer is below. Am I mutating the values of totalPrice and totalItems? If so, how can I update the totalPrice and totalItems without mutating? This is really confusing.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case AddToCart:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.products, action.product],
        totalPrice: action.totalPrice,
        totalItems: action.totalItems,
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

When architecting redux store, the store state should not have a duplication of information; it should comply with normalization concept. 
 Indeed, info like `totalPrice` ,`totalItems` can be definitely concluded from the rest of state.

This total can be concluded/calculated inside `mapStateToProps` , neither in reducer nor in middleware.

If this is clear, you will have two reducers:

1. The first reducer as a database of products : id+ name+ price+....
2. The second reducer is about `Cart` which is a set of shopping items : id + quantity

   I may propose the following state shape :

   ```
   {
     products : {
      'product_1xxx' : {
         id: product_1xxx,
         price :150,
         name: 'T-Shirt'
       } ,

      'product_2yyy' : {
         id: product_2yyy,
         price : 35,
         name: 'Glass'
      } 

    }, 
    //---second reducer--//

    cartItems: {
       [
         {
          'productId': 'product_2yyy',
           quantity: 3
         }
       ]
    }
   ```

   }

The example above means you have 2 products , and the user selects the 2nd product with a quantity of 3 items.

then , the action addToCart will be a shape of `{type, productId, quantity}`

So when user adds/removes items , the action should be handled only by the 2nd reducers (assuming you are using `combineReducers` ).

Also the component (responsible of rendering the total) should  have the following `mapStateToProps` :

```
function mapStateToProps({products, cartItems }) {
   return {
    totalPrice: cartItems.map(({productId, quantity}) => ({quantity, price: products[productId].price  }))
                         .reduce((total, item) => total + (item.price * item.quantity) , 0);
   }
}
```

As you can note, the `price` info is not redundant but it was concluded from the first reducer by joining by productId.